# How to write print statements to a csv file without using csvwriter

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write few print statements along with some variable to a csv file without using csv writer.

```
sys.stdout = open("result.csv", "w")
..///...
print("something",variable)
...///...
.///..
print("something",variable)
..////...
sys.stdout.close()
```

I am using this to start writing to the csv file. But since I am running it from bash I want to have some print some statements from the code to reflect in the bash terminal.

Right now all the print statements are written directly to the csv file. Anyway I can print some statements to the terminal directly or any other way to write to csv file ?

Comment: This stinks of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). *Why* are you replacing `stdout`? Why would you want to write arbitrary non-CSV data to a CSV file? Even if you wanted to, why would you want to bypass `csv.writer` (which is the *only* reasonable way to write CSV matching a consistent dialect)? You've clearly settled on a solution to a problem that makes no sense; what is your actual problem that is making you consider this insane solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way.

```
import sys

variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2

# Open the csv file in writing mode
with open("result.csv", "w") as file:
    # Set the standard output to the csv file
    sys.stdout = file

    # Write to the csv file
    print(f"something1 {variable_1}")
    print(f"something2 {variable_2}")

    # Set the standard output to the console
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

    # Print to the console
    print("This line is printed to the console")
```

`sys.__stdout__` is the default output of the `print` function, thus you should set `sys.stdout` back to the default value (i.e., `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__`) before closing the file, if not, you will get an `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`.

You don't need to care about these things by using [@Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus)'s method in the comment area, his method is more simple and efficient.

```
variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2

# Open the csv file in writing mode
with open("result.csv", "w") as file:

    # Write to the csv file
    print(f"something1 {variable_1}", file=file)
    print(f"something2 {variable_2}", file=file)

    # Print to the console
    print("This line is printed to the console")
```

Comment: Why involve `sys.stdout` when you can do `print(..., file=file)` to use `print` to write to a file?

Comment: @Timus you are right, your way is more simple and efficient. Thanks!